# Nhibernate - QueryOver. IsLike with multiple conditions

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

I couldn't figure out how to create IsLike query with multiple conditions.

```
criteria =  criteria.Add(Restrictions.Like("IpAdress", "%" + request.Keyword + "%") ||
            Restrictions.Like("MacAdress", "%" + request.Keyword + "%") ||
            Restrictions.Like("al.SerialNumber", "%" + request.Keyword + "%"));
```

How to translate query above to IQueryOver format?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You haven't posted what your entities look like, but you could write something along these lines:

```
query.Where(Restrictions.Disjunction()
    .Add(Restrictions.On<Type>(x => x.IpAddress).IsLike(request.Keyword))
    .Add(Restrictions.On<Type>(x => x.MacAdress).IsLike(request.Keyword))
    .Add(Restrictions.On<Type2>(x => x.SerialNumber).IsLike(request.Keyword)));
```

or you could use `||` operator instead of disjunction:

```
query.Where(
    Restrictions.On<Type>(x => x.IpAddress).IsLike(request.Keyword) ||
    Restrictions.On<Type>(x => x.MacAdress).IsLike(request.Keyword) ||
    Restrictions.On<Type2>(x => x.SerialNumber).IsLike(request.Keyword));
```

Here are some similar SO question for more info:
[queryover and (x like 'a' or y like 'a')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4541546/queryover-and-x-like-a-or-y-like-a)
[QueryOver Or with Subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7957733/queryover-or-with-subquery)